# What outbound firewall rules are required to receive Windows Defender definition updates?

Tags: firewall, windows-update

I have outbound blocked in Windows firewall and aren't receiving Defender definition updates via Windows Update. Does anybody know what firewall rules would be required to receive definition updates?

Comment: Same 4 sites as general windows update.

Comment: its a basic but legitme question, why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Defender updates, as with all other MS updates are via HTTPS.  So you will need to allow port 443.

Also note, that if you have any DNS filters, they can cause defender updates to fail as MS uses the same destination servers to provide spam and collect private data from Windows 10 users.  Some DNS filters (ie. PiHole) will block these destinations by default because they may be considered privacy-violating sites.

Answer (score -1):

Within the Windows Defender Firewall area, if you decide to change outbound connections from allow to block you will need to create a new outbound firewall rule specifically allowing the Windows Update service outbound connections.